# How to rename sections in PowerPoint with macro and vba

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm writing a script in VBA to change the titles of the slide to the section title.
I want to find `-` in the section name and change it to `@`
I wrote these codes but I can not save the changes.

```
Sub find()
    Dim i As Long

    Dim curName As String
    Dim newName As String

    With ActivePresentation.SectionProperties
        If ActivePresentation.SectionProperties.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
        For i = 1 To .Count
            curName = .Name(i)
            If Left(curName, 1) = "-" Then
                newName = Replace(curName, "-", "@")
                .Rename(i, newName) = True
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Public Sub RenameSections()

```
Dim counter As Long

Dim currentName As String
Dim newName As String

With ActivePresentation.SectionProperties
    
    ' If there are no sections, exit procedure
    If .Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Loop through each section
    For counter = 1 To .Count
        ' Store current section's name
        currentName = .Name(counter)
        
        ' Check if character is at section name's begining
        If Left(currentName, 1) = "-" Then
            
            newName = Replace(currentName, "-", "@")
            
            .Rename counter, newName
            
        End If
    Next counter
    
End With
```

End Sub

Answer (score 1):

In your code, as far as I can see there are two blocking issues:

1. The `Rename` function call is wrong, you just need to provide two parameters and it should work

```
.Rename i, newName
```

2. You are only looking for the first character to be `-` or not, if you need to replace everything independent of the first character being equal to `-` character, you either need to check all or just Replace everything and rename all without checking the first character.

If I'm correct on my assumption on point 2 here, this would be the code with minimal changes from yours:

```
Sub find()
    Dim i As Long

    Dim curName As String
    Dim newName As String

    With ActivePresentation.SectionProperties
        If ActivePresentation.SectionProperties.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
        For i = 1 To .Count
            curName = .Name(i)
            newName = Replace(curName, "-", "@")
            .Rename i, newName
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some suggestions:

- Change procedure and variables' names to something meaningful
- Indent your code
- If you're using `With` statement, apply it to all the code within (if that's the intention)

Your code's problems:

- You were missing an `End If` (you could notice if you indented your code in the first place)
- You had to change this: `.Rename(i, newName) = True` to this: `.Rename counter, newName`

**Code:**

```
Public Sub RenameSections()
    
    Dim counter As Long
    
    Dim currentName As String
    Dim newName As String
    
    With ActivePresentation.SectionProperties
        
        ' If there are no sections, exit procedure
        If .Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
        
        ' Loop through each section
        For counter = 1 To .Count
            ' Store current section's name
            currentName = .Name(counter)
            
            ' Check if character is at section name's begining
            If Left(currentName, 1) = "-" Then
                
                newName = Replace(currentName, "-", "@")
                
                .Rename counter, newName
                
            End If
        Next counter
        
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: thank you Ricardo, I changed .Rename counter, newName in my code and it wordked. and it should be  If Left(currentName, 1) = "-" Then

Answer (score 0):

make your improvements

```
Sub ChangeTitlePowerpoint()
Dim curSlide As Slide
For Each curSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
    curSlide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Replace(curSlide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text, "–", "@k_g@@dluck")
Next curSlide
End Sub
```

Fonte/Source: [https://learn.microsoft.com/](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.shape.title)